# MySQL REGEXP failing to limit # of occurrences (?!)

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table with a lot of individual words in it (Column name 'qWord') with contents including 'Utility', 'Utter', 'Unicorn' and 'Utile'

I'm trying to do a SELECT to find qWord strings which have at most one instance of the letter 't'.

Using REGEXP I thought it would be a trivial statement like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM entries.qentries 
 WHERE (qWord REGEXP 'T{0,1}')
```

but I'm still getting 'Utter' and 'Utility' in the output -- along with 'Utile' and 'Unicorn'.

So what am I missing here?

(FWIW: MySQL 8.0.11, Community edition running on a Windows 8.1 machine)

Here's the full REGEXP and my apologies for not posting it initially. I'm looking for words composed only of specific letters and that part works fine.

But I also words with a limited number of a given letter, say `t`

```
SELECT * FROM entries.entries WHERE 
(qWord NOT REGEXP 'C|F|G|I|J|K|P|Q|S|V|W|X|Y|Z|-') 
AND (qWord REGEXP 'A|B|D|E|H|L|M|N|O|R|T|U') 
AND (qWord REGEXP 't{0,1}') ;
```

I've also tried `(qWord REGEXP 't{0}|t{1}')` as well as `(qWord REGEXP '(?<=[^t]|^)(t{0}|t{1})(?:[^t]|$)' )`

without success, so I remain stuck

Comment: All your examples match `/T{0}/` because there is not a single `T` in your words. I assume mysql correctly respects case. Try again with `t{0,1}`

Comment: Is the question about how to use regexp, or just how to find words with only one 't' in them?

Comment: Computers are dumb. Computers are like those people who will say "yes" to "do you have one apple" when they have a dozen. Don't ask it "Is there zero or one T", ask it "Is there zero or one T and everything else is not T". Also, UniversE might have a point - it is up to the collation you use whether or not the search is case-sensitive or not, and if it is case-insensitive, there are zero `T` in `"Utter"`.

Comment: Just a quick -- and grateful --  response here. The search is case insensitive by default in this configuration, so t{0,1} should catch it. That syntax does work fine if, for instance, I do t{2.3} to find words with just 2 or 3 "t" values, it just seems confused with the t{0,1} syntax. Also want to note this is just part of a much much longer REGEXP expression -- but the only one which seems to be failing. I've thus isolated it for this posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM entries.qentries 
 WHERE (qWord REGEXP '^[^tT]*[tT]?[^tT]*$')
```

**Explanations:**

- `^`, `$` starting and ending anchors (this is needed to avoid word partial match)
- `[^tT]*` any character that is not a `t` or a `T` 0 or more times
- `[tT]?` at most one occurrence of `t` or `T` (`?` is equivalent to `{0,1}`)
- `[^tT]*` any character that is not a `t` or a `T` 0 or more times

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/t8JRDq/3/)

***Additional Notes:***

`[^tT]` this character range will accept anything that is not a `t` or a `T` (spaces, `.`, `\n` and other characters will also be accepted, you can restrict this if you want to accept only letters and exclude the `t,T` you can use: `[a-su-zA-SU-Z]`, if you want to add other characters to this class, just add them at the end `[a-su-zA-SU-Z -]` will also accept words with spaces and `-`.

Comment: Assuming the `COLLATION` is "case insensitive", you don't need to say `tT`; simply `t` would suffice.

Comment: @RickJames: Completely agree with you!! ;-)

Comment: @RickJames: actually he could also change the `where` clause in `lower(qWord) REGEXP '^[^t]*t?[^t]*$'` or into something like `lower(qword) REGEXP '^[a-su-z -]*t?[a-su-z -]*$'` depending on his exact needs

Comment: `LOWER()` is likely to be more costly than letting Collation take care of it.

Comment: So here's the full REGEXP I'm tryuing to get to work, and myu apologies for not posting it initially:

Comment: Here's how that last comment should have read (sigh): Here's the full REGEXP and my apologies for not posting it initially. I'm looking for words composed only of specific letters and that part works fine. But I also words with a limited number of a given letter, say "t"

SELECT * FROM entries.entries WHERE 
(qWord NOT REGEXP 'C|F|G|I|J|K|P|Q|S|V|W|X|Y|Z|-') 
AND (qWord REGEXP 'A|B|D|E|H|L|M|N|O|R|T|U')
AND (qWord REGEXP 't{0,1}') ;

I've also tried
(qWord REGEXP 't{0}|t{1}')  as well as 
(qWord REGEXP '(?<=[^t]|^)(t{0}|t{1})(?:[^t]|$)' ) 
 
without success, so I remain stuck.

Comment: @Mike: could you gather the exact requirements for the where clause? We will define a regex that will meet all your requirements at once. The way regex works is to define a specific pattern a kind of blue print to filter/match/extract strings from inputs. You should not separate all your requirements but group them in one single regex. You can use https://regex101.com/ and http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: @Mike: Have you tried my SQL? Does it work as expected?

Comment: Alan, I have tried MySQL commands but after some study,thought that REGEXP would be simpler programming. Any "SELECT" statement I could come up with would have been hugely long and complex. I'm definitely open to suggestion though!

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding to such useful comments and questions. Allan, here's the simplest way I can phrase it:
From a (long) list of words, I'm trying to isolate words containing only a specific set of letters (and no others), and within that result set each letter can appear from 0 to M times within a word. The value of "M" varies by letter.
The trial code I've put here focuses only on the letter 't'. I realize the length of full REGEXP will be quite long (it will be developed programmatically). At this point I'd be thrilled if I could just get it working with 't'.
Clear as mud?